# How can I label x and y of a line_chart

Tags: python, dataframe, charts, streamlit

I have a `line_chart` below, plotted with **`st.line_chart()`**, how can I label `x` and `y`?
I tried with **matplotlib** but I couldn't achieve my expected output.

```py
import streamlit as st

st.line_chart(df)
```

[image]

My expected output:
[image]

Comment: According to the [doc](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/charts/st.line_chart) that is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, **st.altair_chart** can help you achieve that expected result but if your **df** is complex, you will have to put in a lot of work, that depends on how worthy your expected output is.
Refer to this [altair_chart doc](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/charts/st.altair_chart#:%7E:text=st.pyplot-,st.altair_chart,-st.vega_lite_chart) in the streamlit platform, where you can find different illustrations and how to handle them.